# Android Camera record opengl filter

Tags: android, video, opengl-es, camera, recording

I am building an application that will use a live filter on the camera's preview and I need to record a video of this filtered preview.

I have already checked the following:

- Graphika CameraCaptureActivity, have a preview with a filter but the recording does not include the filter. Unfortunately GLSurfaceView does not supports this. I could render twice the filter - once on the preview and once on the recording frames - but this is not very efficient.
- Graphika RecordFBOActivity, records opengl video but not from the camera.
- bigflake CameraToMpegTest, records from camera but preview is not displayed on the screen.

There is a big choice of solutions and component combination on this and I am quite confused so how this can be implemented?
I am new on this area so if you can point to a working example it will be great.

Thank you